# Match multiple object fields with an input value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am working on a large product datasets and I need to filter through the products list based on the user's input value. My product dataset looks something like this:

```
const products = [
  {id: 0, name: "Product1", brand: "Theraflu", itemCode: "THE110", price: 5.45},
  {id: 1, name: "Product2", brand: "Benadryl", itemCode: "BEN121", price: 7.05},
  {id: 2, name: "Product3", brand: "Listerine", itemCode: "LIS204", price: 4.55},
  {id: 3, name: "Product4", brand: "Tylenol", itemCode: "TYL116", price: 6.10},
];
```

I was able to filter the product list based on the different fields available in each individual product object like this:

```
const keys = ["name", "brand", "itemCode"];

const getFilteredProducts = (filterText) => {
  const newProducts = products.filter(product => keys.some(key => product[key].toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())));
  
  return newProducts;
}

console.log(getFilteredProducts("Tylenol"));
```

This code actually works when I filter the product based on individual field. However, when I try to combine different fields like:

```
console.log(getFilteredProducts("product4 Tylenol"));
```

The returned value of this is an empty array. Is there a way to achieve this without altering the existing filtering functionality?

Comment: What do you want as an output? A union (all elements with either 'product4' or 'Tylenol') or an intersection (all elements with both 'product4' and 'Tylenol').

Comment: I want all products that match the input value. A user can search for just "product4" or "Tylenol" or "product4 Tylenol" and still gets the products matching the entered input text.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What if they ask for 'product3 Tylenol'. Will they get both products 4 and 3, or neither of them?

Comment: Yes they should get both products 4 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you'll need to search each word of the `filterText` on its own. Maybe something like this:

```
const keys = ["name", "brand", "itemCode"];

const getFilteredProducts = (filterText) => {
  const filterWords = filterText.split(" ");
  const newProducts = [];

  for (const word of filterWords) {
    newProducts.push(
      products.filter(product => keys.some(key =>
        product[key].toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase())
      ))
    );  
  }

  return [].concat(...newProducts).filter((value, index, self) => 
    self.findIndex((m) => m.id === value.id) === index
  );
}

console.log(getFilteredProducts("Tylenol Product3"));
```